# Typescript: How to access "two levels above" properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

Quick question - How to access "two levels above" properties? 
Testing example in TypeScript:

```
export class Test {
    testVariable: string;
    constructor() { }

    TestFunction() {
        MyFunctions.Proxy.Join() { //some made up function from other module
            //HERE
            //How can I here access testVariable property of Test class?
        }
    }
}
```

Or is it even possible to access such a properties in TypeScript (or JavaScript in general)?

**Edit + answer:** As my question was not clear enough I bring some new info about this issue. 
It is very commonly asked question by starting programmers.

Issue here is that `this` changes its context - firstly it refers to class Test, then it refers to my inner function - `Join()`. To achieve correctness we have to either use lambda expressions for inner function call or use some substitute value for `this`.

First solution is in the accepted answer.

Second is this:

```
export class Test {
    testVariable: string;
    constructor() { }

    TestFunction() {
        var myClassTest: Test = this;
        MyFunctions.Proxy.Join() { //some made up function from other module
            myClassTest.testVariable; //approaching my class propery in inner function through substitute variable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your syntax isn't valid to begin with, so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Unless you have access to the instance variable that contains the property you need, you can't walk the parent chain, unless you have properties created that would allow you to do that.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. I gave just a test example and didn't notice its not valid. My point was simply if I can approach properties (some variables) that are two levels above my function = using "this" keyword would lead to my above-function and not to the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use fat-arrow syntax, it will preserve your lexical scope:

```
export class Test {
    testVariable: string;
    constructor() { }

    TestFunction() {
        var MyFunctions = {
            Proxy: {
                Join: function() {}
            }
        };

        MyFunctions.Proxy.Join = () => {
            alert(this.testVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the fat arrow just helped me keep my scope for closing a modal after setTimeout, thanks for this, it helped out loads